# How To Unit Test a WFC Web Socket

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, websocket

I am trying to create a unit test in order to step through my code to get access to an error that occurs when I try to access data via Entity Framework.  I have not found good examples from my searches for answers.  I try to create a client in the second line of the code and I get a a "client.InnerChannel threw an exception of type System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException" when I examine the client.InnerChannel in the debugger.  The WebSocket works fine in my client doing the simple example from the tutorial but throws an error that I can't examine as soon as I try to access the DB via Entity Framework.

I am working off code provided in this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619343/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part

My interfaces are defined below:

```
namespace PriceBlotterWebSocket
{
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IPriceBlotterCallback))]
    public interface IPriceBlotterWebSocket
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        Task SendMessageToServer(Message msg);
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPriceBlotterCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
       Task SendMessageToClient(Message msg);
    }

}
```

And my unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    internal class CallBackHandler : IPriceBlotterCallback
    {
        public async Task SendMessageToClient(Message msg)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(msg);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var context = new InstanceContext(new CallBackHandler());
        var client = new PriceBlotteWebSocketService.PriceBlotterWebSocketClient("CustomBinding_IPriceBlotterWebSocket");
        //Why can't I call client.SendMessageToServer ? 
    }

}
```

Test Project client config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_IPriceBlotterWebSocket">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport>
                        <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" subProtocol="soap" />
                    </httpTransport>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="ws://localhost:54426/Service1.svc" binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IPriceBlotterWebSocket"
                contract="PriceBlotteWebSocketService.IPriceBlotterWebSocket"
                name="CustomBinding_IPriceBlotterWebSocket" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: For a **test only**, could you change the `internal class CallBackHandler` to `public class CallBackHandler`?

Comment: No luck, thanks though

Comment: I think there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach.  The client object doesn't even have the method SendMessage available.

Comment: How did you get the IPriceBlotterCallback interface in your client?

Comment: Using javascript,                                                                                           ws = new WebSocket("ws://devserver:1.com:8120/Service1.svc");